# $(\sqrt{x})^2$ doesn't have domain for negative real numbers even if its root gets canceled out. why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got this problem in an algebra course on brilliant.org.

even the graphing calculator in geogebra.com only shows the range of function as only positive real numbers.
need an explaination on why the domain of the function is absolute.

Comment: It's because $\sqrt{x}$ does not exist (disregarding complex numbers) for negative reals. The function $\sqrt{x}^2$ first sends $x$ to $\sqrt{x}$ and then squares the result, if there is no result to square, the function does not exist there.

Comment: How can the root of a negative number get canceled out when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Now @aman has explained this, you might want to see whether you can predict what the software plots for $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take the squareroot of a negative number.

So take $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{2}$, $g(x)=x^2$

We are considering the function $g(f(x))$ This means applying f first, the g.
But f is not defined on the domain of negative numbers. Thus, neither if $g(f)$

Comment: Thanks bro. So it's the order of the function that gives the solidity of the domain. Got it